# Error on Arithmetic Coding Compression Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement arithmetic coding which is a compression algorithm. Here is the compression code.When I compiled it

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: arithmetic.FrequencyTable
    at arithmetic.ArithmeticCompress.main(ArithmeticCompress.java:35)

It is giving me this error.

source

```
package arithmetic;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;


public class ArithmeticCompress {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    File inputFile  = new File("D:\\5.txt");
    File outputFile = new File("D:\\new1.txt");

    // Read input file once to compute symbol frequencies
    //Line no 35
    FrequencyTable freqs = getFrequencies(inputFile);
    freqs.increment(256);  // EOF symbol gets a frequency of 1

    // Read input file again, compress with arithmetic coding, and write output file
    try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {
        try (BitOutputStream out = new BitOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)))) {
            writeFrequencies(out, freqs);
            compress(freqs, in, out);
        }
    }
}


// Returns a frequency table based on the bytes in the given file.
// Also contains an extra entry for symbol 256, whose frequency is set to 0.
private static FrequencyTable getFrequencies(File file) throws IOException {
    FrequencyTable freqs = new SimpleFrequencyTable(new int[257]);
    try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        while (true) {
            int b = input.read();
            if (b == -1)
                break;
            freqs.increment(b);
        }
    }
    return freqs;
}


// To allow unit testing, this method is package-private instead of private.
static void writeFrequencies(BitOutputStream out, FrequencyTable freqs) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        writeInt(out, 32, freqs.get(i));
}


// To allow unit testing, this method is package-private instead of private.
static void compress(FrequencyTable freqs, InputStream in, BitOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ArithmeticEncoder enc = new ArithmeticEncoder(out);
    while (true) {
        int symbol = in.read();
        if (symbol == -1)
            break;
        enc.write(freqs, symbol);
    }
    enc.write(freqs, 256);  // EOF
    enc.finish();  // Flush remaining code bits
}


// Writes an unsigned integer of the given bit width to the given stream.
private static void writeInt(BitOutputStream out, int numBits, int value) throws IOException {
    if (numBits < 0 || numBits > 32)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    for (int i = numBits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        out.write((value >>> i) & 1);  
}
```

}

Comment: I have marked. I am trying to run this program.

Comment: Where is defined your FrequencyTable class?

Answer (score -1):

Well it's a little bit weird because such source code shouldn't even compile (so there shouldn't be any RuntimeException): because your code is referencing class FrequencyTable, but that class is not defined in your code and it's not even imported? Not sure. However normally, this would lead to a compilation error and you shouldn't be able to run such code - here I guess that you are using some IDE (like NetBeans, maybe eclipse) which allows you to run the code even if it doesn't compile -> but it'll fail during rutime.

I advise to fully rebuild (clean and compile) your project in your IDE to show errors you might have in the code...

Comment: Was this answer helpful, @Megha ?